# java server listen to http request

Tags: java, http, post, server

I have a code that handle the post and get request . but it should response when the post request come . I dont want to use servlet because it need the tomcat or jetty and its become more complex .
how I should know post request recived ?

```
 private void sendPost() throws Exception {

    String url = "https://selfsolve.apple.com/wcResults.do";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    while (true) {
        HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();

        System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
        http.sendGet();

        System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
        http.sendPost();

    }
}
```

Comment: First install TamperData in FireFox, or some other develop plugin in your browser. Then you can check the actual communication, and gather knowledge. w3c.org has an extensive reference on the HTTP protocol. To make your own server (ServerSocket, Socket) is relative easy. However an embedded jetty should develop faster.

Comment: @JoopEggen : thank you for help . how can I start with jetty ? I look at some sites but it seem so difficault ... can you show me some easy and fast tutorial ?

Comment: (Personally I make maven projects, so library dependencies are handled automatically.) And for jetty [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty).